# Requesting Apps Script ConferenceDataService access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, conference

Google Apps Script recently launched the ability for 3rd parties to create custom Calendar conference handle ConferenceDataService you must be whitelisted, otherwise it will return "ConferenceDataService is not defined".

Does anyone know how I can get or request access to ConferenceDataService. Other addon developers have already implemented it, so I know it is up and running.
[See Zoom addon for google calendar](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/zoom_for_gsuite/364750910244?hl=en&pann=caw)

Comment: Hi Zuza, did you get any solution for this?